# Is it possible to create a clan, leave it, and then create another one?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of Clans, I am not sure who I want to form a clan with or what I should call it, so I am reviewing my options. I know that it is *not* possible for me to rename a clan or to delete a clan (by this I mean manually deleting it myself, not taking some action that causes it to be deleted). I know that it *is* possible to create a clan, leave it, and then join another clan.

**Is it possible to create a clan, leave that clan, and then create a new one?**

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Is it poorly written, inaccurate, a duplicate, or just a stupid question? If so, why? I would appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually,  you can delete a clan. If there are no more users in a clan then it will automatically be deleted. You can also leave a clan and create a new one, you have to pay a fee to create it though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. However, you will have to pay the usual 40,000 gold fee to create the clan if you make a new one. As soon as you are not a member of your former clan, you can crete a new one.

Comment: You need 40,000 gold to reconstruct the clan tower, not to make a clan. It takes 4,000 I believe to make a clan.

Comment: @adiosToreador, it takes 40,000 gold to make a new clan. If you want to see more about clans, look at the page on clans (http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Politics)

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I haven't made a clan in a long time

Comment: @adiosToreador simple mistake :o)